# error in servlet response getOutputStream()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jboss

i have this problema i create and pdf in class an call with page jsp.
This is the code. The pdf work but in the console i have a error.

index.jsp -> this is the page in jsp

```
 <%@page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="pdf.pdf.Pdf"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%


    String path=application.getRealPath("/");
    System.out.println("Path: "+path);

    //CuponPDF_old c=new CuponPDF_old(request, response,path,Estudiante);
    //Cupon.CuponPDFNew c=new Cupon.CuponPDFNew(request, response,path,Estudiante);
     //CuponPDFNew c = new CuponPDFNew(request,response,path,Estudiante);

     Pdf c = new Pdf(request,response);
      c.generarCupon();
 %>   

</body>
</html>
```

Pdf.java --> this is the class create in a Package

```
package pdf.pdf;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


public class Pdf {

    HttpServletResponse response=null;

    public Pdf (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse _response) {

        response=_response;


    }


    public Document cuponPage (Document document) throws DocumentException
    {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        PdfPCell cell;

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
        cell.setColspan(3);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(cell);





            document.add(table);
        /*float widCPrincipal[]={97,3};                     

        PdfPTable tablePrincipal=new PdfPTable(2);
        tablePrincipal.setWidths(widCPrincipal);
        document.add(tablePrincipal);

        */
        return document;

    }



    public void generarCupon()throws IOException, DocumentException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
     {
           Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);




           try {
                 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                 PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
                 document.open();



                     document=cuponPage(document);
                 }





         catch(DocumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Error:"+e.getMessage());
         }
         document.close();     





        }
}
```

And the error. -> this the information about the error in console.

```
14:31:02,830 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó excepción
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:619)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:188)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

thx for help.

Comment: The error is in `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`. Nothing to do with iText whatso ever. The error message is perfectly clear even to me, and I don't even speak Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP page you first set the content type to text/html

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

And then you already send some HTML content

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
```

As you already sent content, you now cannot change any headers anymore.

Now you call your `Pdf` class. This class tries to set the content type

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Which as mentioned doesn't work anymore. This may be what the warming tells you, I cannot read it as it is in some foreign language, Spanish as EJP assumes.

Then your class generates the pdf into the result stream, and thereafter you again send some HTML:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Thus, your JSP page generated a text/html typed response which contains some html tags, a pdf, and again some html tags. This is neither valid html nor valid pdf.

Generally one should not generate pdfs (or binary results in general) in a JSP page. But if one does, one has to take care not to send any html with it by accident, not even some empty lines.

Thus, remove all that html and any empty lines outsides the `<% ...%>` block.